# Spectrum.js not initializing when used in angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, background-color, color-picker

I am using [angular-spectrum-colorpicker](https://github.com/Jimdo/angular-spectrum-colorpicker) to use [spectrum.js](https://bgrins.github.io/spectrum/) in my code. It works basically fine except the value is not initialized with model. The following is the settings I used:

```
<spectrum-colorpicker ng-model="backgroundColor"
                        options="{
                                 flat: true,
                                 preferredFormat: 'hex',
                                 showInput: true,
                                 showButtons: false,
                                 clickoutFiresChange: true,
                                 }">
</spectrum-colorpicker>
```

And here is a jsbin to demostrate the problem. You can see that it works fine except the color is not correctly initialized at the beginning. You may reproduce the error by toggling the output pannel.

[JSBin](https://jsbin.com/pugitotade/1/edit?html,js,output)

What have I missed or is it a bug that I should report on github?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about passing `color` by option?

```
  <spectrum-colorpicker ng-model="backgroundColor"
                        options="{
                                 color: backgroundColor,
                                 flat: true,
                                 preferredFormat: 'hex',
                                 showInput: true,
                                 showButtons: false,
                                 clickoutFiresChange: true,
                                 }">
```

Comment: It works, but better try with the jsbin I provided before you answer? It is odd to start an answer with "How about"

Comment: @cytsunny Well, I have tried it in jsbin. Next time I will use another phrase.